# How do I get Blade syntax highlighting in Aptana

Tags: syntax-highlighting, laravel, laravel-blade

Does anyone know how to get syntax highlighting for the Blade Templating language used by Laravel in Aptana?

I found this but can't find a repository from which I can install anything like this.

https://github.com/Medalink/Laravel-Blade

Answer (score -5):

https://github.com/Medalink/Laravel-Blade/blob/master/Blade.tmLanguage 
Here you got highlighting for sublime text 2.
I don't know how these type of file implicate with aptana. You can search and convert it.
Remember: Aptana is like Eclipse (it's built on top of eclipse though) so you can search for eclipse as weoll.

Good luck with that.

PS 
Y U NOT USE SUBLIME? :)

Comment: Hi Matiit, I had looked at that all right (and linked to it in my question). I tried a lot of searches based on Eclipse as I know that pretty much anything Eclipse based works in Aptana. 

I haven't tried Sublime Text - does it offer the same sort of feature set as Aptana? SVN/GIT, terminal, configurable workspaces, etc etc

Comment: Sublime Text 2 is nifty but nagging to pay $60 for a license. It does not have the same features as a true IDE; it is closer to VIM, Notepad++, and other editors. I use NetBeans and am working on converting the Smarty plugin to work since a lot of the templating is the same (except what mimics Razor from MVC4).

Comment: Link content no longer exists.

Comment: I've switched to Sublime now, very happy to have made the change. Bye bye aptana!