# How to make Aptana shows Laravel statements color in .php files(support Laravel)?

Tags: php, aptana, laravel

Sublime Text 2 in my tutorial video shows Laravel statement color well, the same code in my Aptana is just white(in a *.php file), it treats the code as plain HTML text, how can I set Aptana to show code with color(support Laravel)?

```
@layout('master')
@section('main')
    @foreach($users as $user)
        {{$user->email}}
    @endforeach
@endsection
@section('nav')
    <li>Details</li>
    @parent
@endsection
```

All above codes are white except <li></li> tags, that is not the way I want.

I don't know how to set Aptana Studio 3, I need help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631425/how-do-i-get-blade-syntax-highlighting-in-aptana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 provides a package for Laravel Blade templates - this means it 'understands' the code and can colour it correctly.

This option does not exist in Aptana - so you cannot do it.

Comment: However if you felt inclined to make an Aptana Ruble to support laravel blade syntax, this would colour your code and (again if you were inclined to add it to the ruble) could provide you with code suggestions as well.